# How to add more storage to Ubuntu server 12.04 for my website?

Tags: 12.04, server, storage

My main hard drive is being used both as the installation and for my website is there a way Ubuntu can use the second hard drive for my website ? do I have to copy my website to the new drive ? if yes is it going to be difficult ?

```
 ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 26 2013 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jan 27 2013 wordpress -> ../sites-available/wordpress
```

Comment: Yes i'm using Apache2.

Comment: Yeah, you can copy it, and change the root directory `DocumentRoot` in Apache2 site file `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`. replace *000-default.conf* with your own site file.

Comment: I'm sorry but which site file ? I'm using Joomla.

Comment: I tryed to open 000-default.conf but there is no file it creates a new one.

Comment: Could you add the contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wordpress` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I assume you are using the default apache root folder /var/www**

*If you don't understand what it does, Leave it!*

- Use *Disks* utility: Select the new hard drive → Create New Partition (as Ext4)
- Still with *Disks* utility: Edit Mount Options, something like this

[image: Mount options]

- Mount the new partition
- Stop Apache

  ```
  sudo service apache2 stop
  ```
- Copy files with *-a* option to preserve all

  ```
  sudo cp -a /var/www /media/files/
  ```
- Edit `DocumentRoot` in `000-default` and  `wordpress` to follow the new path.

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
  sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wordpress
  ```

Example: `DocumentRoot /var/www` → `DocumentRoot /media/files/www`

- Start Apache again:

  ```
  sudo service apache2 start
  ```
- Test it for sometime, if OK Delete old files.

  ```
  sudo rm -r /var/www/*
  ```